# Any observed example of a planet hitting its parent star?

Tags: impact, orbital-migration

I did some research and a likely candidate is hot Jupiter type migration where the orbit didn't stabilize and crashed into the parent star.

Comment: Why the downvote? This looks like a perfectly valid question to me.

Comment: If you google "star eating planet," Google seems to have quite a few results.  Here is an example of one: https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/hubble/science/planet-eater.html

Comment: Cody What I had in mind was more of an impact rather than a gradual mass loss, hence the word "crash".

Comment: Comets regularly get vaporised for getting too near the Sun, it is believed. Obviously "comets" aren't planets, but there is plainly a parallel.